# how to add fast data in view inflate with layout

Tags: android, spinner, layout-inflater

its is working fine but its taking too much time for arraylist size 7000 . is there any other way to display this report in fast way.to display 1000 row its taking 3 minutes which very huge time .can we use another way to make this report instead of uving view inflate with layout which will work fast.Thank in advance

```
  spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.searchableSpinnerLedgerReport);
            spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(LedgerReportActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,numberlist));
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(position==-1){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "plz select number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
    
                        String snumber= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    
                         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList=ledgerReportDataCon.getSelectedReport(snumber);     //size of comming data is 7000
                         Log.d("size of report list", String.valueOf(myList.size()));
    //                     Log.d("name",snumber);
                         if(Float.parseFloat (myList.get(0).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_cLOSING))>0)
                         {
                             tclosingblnc.setText(myList.get(0).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_cLOSING));
                         }
                         else {
                             tclosingblnc2.setText(myList.get(0).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_cLOSING));
                         }
    
                        if(Float.parseFloat(myList.get(0).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_oPENING))>0)
                        {
                            topeningblnc.setText(myList.get(0).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_oPENING));
                        }
                        else {
                            topeningblnc2.setText(myList.get(0).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_oPENING));
                        }
    
                        for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
    
                            String ledgertype=myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_lEDGERTYPE);
                            String narration=myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_nARRATION);
    
    
                            final View partyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ledger_report_item, null, false);
    
                              LinearLayout headerLayout=(LinearLayout) partyView.findViewById(R.id.headder);
                              TextView particular = (TextView) partyView.findViewById(R.id.particular);
                              TextView vchType = (TextView) partyView.findViewById(R.id.vchType);
                              TextView debit = (TextView) partyView.findViewById(R.id.debit);
                              TextView credit = (TextView) partyView.findViewById(R.id.credit);
                              TextView date = (TextView) partyView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                              TextView vchno = (TextView) partyView.findViewById(R.id.vchno);
    
    
                            particular.setText( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_pARTICULARS));
                            vchType.setText( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_vCHTYPE));
                            date.setText( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_vCHDATE));
                            vchno.setText( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_vCHNUM));
    
                            if (ledgertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Dr"))
                            {
                                debit.setText( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_lEDGERAMT));
                                totaldebit=totaldebit+Float.parseFloat( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_lEDGERAMT));
                            }
                            else if (ledgertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Cr"))
                            {
                                credit.setText( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_lEDGERAMT));
                                totalcredit=totalcredit+Float.parseFloat( myList.get(i).get(ConstLedgerReport.key_lEDGERAMT));
    
                            }
    
                            listViewLayout.addView(partyView);
    
                            String[] itemArr=narration.split("~");
    
    //                        Log.d("first array is ....: ", Arrays.toString(itemArr));
    
                            headerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            if(!narration.equalsIgnoreCase("Array")) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < itemArr.length; j++) {
                                    headerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
    
                                    final View itemListView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ledger_report_itemlist, null, false);
    
                                    TextView iname = (TextView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.iname);
                                    TextView iqty = (TextView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.iqty);
                                    TextView iunit = (TextView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.iunit);
                                    TextView irate = (TextView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.irate);
                                    TextView itotal = (TextView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.itotal);
    
                                    String temp1 = itemArr[j].replace("]][[", ",");
                                    String temp2 = temp1.replace("[[", "");
                                    String temp3 = temp2.replace("]]", "");
    
                                    String[] itemArrList = temp3.split(",");
    //                                Log.d("second array is ....: ", Arrays.toString(itemArrList));
    
                                    iname.setText(itemArrList[0]);
                                    iqty.setText(itemArrList[4]);
                                    iunit.setText(itemArrList[1]);
                                    irate.setText(itemArrList[5]);
                                    itotal.setText(itemArrList[7]);
    
                                    listViewLayout.addView(itemListView);
    //                                Log.d("created view msz", String.valueOf(j));
    
                                }
                            }
    
                        }
                        tdebit.setText(String.valueOf(totaldebit));
                        tcredit.setText(String.valueOf(totalcredit));
    
                    }
                }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QyBy.jpg)

Comment: Buddy, use a RecyclerView: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: is it possible to assign value in recyvlerView as i am displaying in my code i want value in that same order

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DineshGangwar yes

Comment: two time i m infalting the layout coz i have two time of data is report u h=can see so for that i have to use recyclerview inside recyclerview coz the item data row are not fix . then how to do this task

Comment: i have data in form ledger and item and one ledger can have diff diff number of item then how to display this . ledger with their item list

Comment: i have mentioned the screenshot of  report i want to make